# secure streaming of videos

Tags: security, streaming, lightbox, lighttpd, jwplayer

im using jwplayer
i want the users to view the videos but not download them
generating hashed url of videos was the one i found to do it
im using lighttpd mod on the server that creates the hash, and using it i create the url for the videos
timeout : expire every 30 minutes from when hash is created

the problems comes when i play the videos the second time

the page loads as follows:
the page loads, there are currently 2 videos that show on each page, a div is created for each of the videos where the jwplayer installs itself, the video plays when the thumbnails for the videos are clicked each time, then the div loads in a lightbox/overlay and the videos are supposed to play

each video on the page plays the first time, but not the subsequent times, it gives the error that it cannot find the file

Answer (score 0):

mod_fast_secure_download is some way you can go.
users still will be able in theory to download.

I have similar issue, but I try to do lighty to hit a script after video is downloaded

Comment: yes i did quite similar, the downloaded link could be used only once and was available some amount of time so i had to run scripts for every time the link was used and after time out of the hashed url

Comment: it was so complicated and so brain-wracking that once i finished, it was fulfilling that i decided to write a blog for it http://goldprogramming.blogspot.com/2011/11/secure-streaming-of-media-on-your-site.html

Answer (score 0):

I have been using StreamingVideoProvider and can surely say security and protection is their key strength. They have a very strong HLS encryption ( including cookie and IP hotlinking protection ) which I highly recommend. You can check below:

http://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/video-hls-encryption-hotlinking.html