# Password protect live video stream using jwplayer

Tags: php, apache, streaming, jwplayer

So, here's my scenario:

I have a site where I can stream a live video feed from.  The site is hosted using Apache, PHP, and MySQL.  Users can log in to get access to the site through accounts stored in a mysql db.  When going to the page where a user can actually watch the stream, the site is using jwplayer to load() a specific URL.  The stream itself comes from an internal server process on another port. However, due to jwplayer being instantiated on the client side, I must pass a URL to it that is accessible remotely.  For right now, I'm using Apache ProxyPass to proxy this url to the internal server process and that works just fine.  The problem is that anyone could simply type in this url passed to jwplayer into VLC (as an example) and get the stream no problem.

Is there a way I can "proxy" a request to the internal server process using PHP where I can first authenticate the current user from the mysql db?

I've tried using Basic Apache Auth on the specific url path and that DOES prompt for a basic auth username and password.  That works to prevent someone from hot-linking to my stream in VLC.  However, I don't want users to have to use the basic auth login style and I'd like to continue using my mysql db authentication system.  Is there a simple way that I can authenticate a user for the Apache Basic auth from a successful login to a PHP page?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting problem! Searching for a possible answer I found a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738951/secure-streaming-of-videos?rq=1) about the issue. In the comments I found a [blog](http://goldprogramming.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/secure-streaming-of-media-on-your-site.html) that explain how an user with the same problem went through it. Hope it helps!

Comment: We have a little bit of information here, as well - http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/securing-your-content/